# How does one create a custom dataset of images with masks for image segmentation?(specifically for Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, image-segmentation

Every tutorial I find involves using a pre-made, but the project I'm trying to do is image segmentation on pictures if playing cards. The dataset will be one I create but I'm finding little to no resources about creating the dataset and needed image masks. Any help would be great!

Comment: This [tool](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/via-1.0.6.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Here is a relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58958450/1435741

Answer (score 1):

I use Gimp (https://www.gimp.org/) with layers. You can use several useful tools, such as the "BucketFill", to quickly color a region. Then you just have to export the layers to a new file to obtain the mask. VGG image annotator is also useful ([https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/via-1.0.6.html](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/software/via/via-1.0.6.html))

For 3D images you can use VTK and ITKsnap (http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php) for volume identification, visualization and exporting. MIPAV (https://mipav.cit.nih.gov/) is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

[VGG Image Annotator (VIA)](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/software/via/), here is a [quick demo](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/software/via/via_demo.html). There is also [labelme](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme)